# PostgreSQL 12.0 Git Bash on windows struggling with createDB

Tags: postgresql

I've installed postgresql onto my pc and am trying to use the "createdb" function through git bash. I was just curious why it is asking me for a password for what i'm intending to be the name of the database i'm trying to create. I can confirm that I've started and restarted postgresql working locally on my PC.

My command:

```
$ psql createdb foo
Password for user foo: <(not really sure what to put here)>
```

Error:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "foo"
```

Answer (score 2):

`createdb` is a command line program just like `psql`. And the first parameter passed to is, is assumed to be the name of the new database. As all Postgres command line clients assume the current operating system user as the database user, it's better to pass the superuser explicitly to the command line programs. So to create a database named foo, use:

```
createdb -U postgres foo
```

Or from inside `psql` use the SQL command `CREATE DATABASE`

```
psql -U postgres -d template1
template1=# create database foo;
```

Comment: I'm currently doing this udacity course and the online video doesn't need to include "-u postgres" in the command. Is there any reason why I always need to do this?

Comment: @JackKoltermann "-U postgres" specifies that you are logging in as the 'postgres' user. It will default to the user account you are using. In your course you are likely either using the postgres account or an account that you added to the database

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what if user has password?

Comment: @Omar: then you need to enter it

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name command    "createdb -U postgres demo" is not working, takes forever and does nothing I am using git bash on windows

Comment: Why "git bash"? Why not use the native command line (`cmd`)? After all `createdb.exe` is a standard Windows executable.